# Awk/Sed how to change a camel url path to a underscore path?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have the following text:

```
SendNoticeMsg (api.post = "/test/SendNoticeMsg")
```

And I want to change the text to be:

```
SendNoticeMsg (api.post = "/test/send_notice_msg")
```

I tried to use this sed script:

```
sed -E 's/(\/test\/.*)([A-Z]).*\"/\1\2_\L/'
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't want to change all camelcase to underscores. So that answer seems not to work in this situation

Comment: You should expand your sample input/output to contain more than just that one simple sunny day case, e.g. include cases with multiple contiguous upper case letters and anything else you think might be non-obvious/trivial to handle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to follow the link posted by Aleksey, then here is the help for you:

```
echo /test/SendNoticeMsg | sed -E 's|/test/([A-Z])([a-z]+)([A-Z])([a-z]+)([A-Z])([a-z]+)|/test/\L\1\2_\L\3\4_\L\5\6|g'
```

Comment: `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` mean different sets of characters in different locales (e.g. `[a-z]` could mean `aAbBcC...z` and `[A-Z]` in that locale would mean `AbBcC...zZ`), you should use the POSIX `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` character classes for portability. Note that while that solution will work for the one example posted, it won't work in general, e.g. if the input has 2 or 4 upper case letters instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$ cat underscore.txt
SendNoticeMsg (api.post = "/test/SendNoticeMsg")
$ perl -pe ' s/(?:\/test\/)(\S+)/$s=$1;$s=~s!([A-Z])!$i++?"_".lc($1):lc($1)!ge;"\/test\/".$s/mge ' underscore.txt
SendNoticeMsg (api.post = "/test/send_notice_msg")
$
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk 'match($0,"(.*/test/)(.)(.*)",a){ gsub(/[[:upper:]]/,"_&",a[3]); $0=a[1] tolower(a[2] a[3]) } 1' file
SendNoticeMsg (api.post = "/test/send_notice_msg")
```